# Grails creating drop down from minute field

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using following script to create a drop down for minute field but it is not working as it should. Following is the code which i am currently using.

```
<%def minuts=['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09',10..59] %>
<g:select class="input-small" name="minute" from="${minuts}" value="${minute}"/>
```

all i want is to create an array of following data..
00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14...........59.

What is the smartest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like:

```
<% def minuts = (0..59).collect { String.format( '%02d', it ) } %>
```

Not sure I 100% got the question..

Comment: Now move it to a taglib and make it a tag

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
<% def minuts = (0..59).collect { g.formatNumber(number: it, minIntegerDigits: 2) } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<% def minuts = (0..59)*.toString()*.padLeft(2,'0') %>
```